# Is there a way to filter and aggregate Kafka records without ktable,kstream?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have records on Kafka. I want to consume filtered (maybe on specific column or timestamp column) and aggregate records like sum.

How can I do that? I ve searched on google and I know I can do it with ksqlDB but how can I do that without ktable,kstream...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not specified in your question what you found on Google precisely, but you have many options for stream processing data in Kafka, including:

- Kafka Streams - this is part of Apache Kafka.
- ksqlDB - a source-available project from Confluent
- Apache Flink
- Spark (Structured) Streaming
- etc
- etc

Comment: thanks for answer Robin, with Kafka Streams  can I get from kafka just last 1 hour record and sum one column in those records. But I do not want use client tool to aggregate data  I mean f.e. python I can consume records then I can aggregate but I want to get it from kafka

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar If you want to use Kafka with Python, try looking at PySpark or `faust`, both of which are "client" tools, so its unclear what else you want

Comment: @OneCricketeer can I aggregate records without client tools?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar All Kafka Consumers are considered as "clients", so no?